# Does anyone have the same first, middle and last name? List them and their full address

Tags: mysql

We have the select statements but unable to return more than 1 person. We know there are two people in the database that fulfills the requirement though.

```
From Person P
GROUP BY First_Name, Mid_Name, Last_Name
HAVING COUNT(*)>1;
```

```
| First_Name | Mid_Name | Last_Name | Street    |
+------------+----------+-----------+-------------+
| Steven    | Lee   | SHAFFER   | 939 POPE RD |
+------------+----------+-----------+-------------+
```

Comment: You mean there are two person with name as 'Steven Lee SHAFFER'?

Answer (score 0):

Building on your attempt, you can join the table with an aggregate query:

```
select p.*
from person p
inner join (
    select first_name, mid_name, last_name
    from person
    group by first_name, mid_name, last_name
    having count(*) > 1
) x 
    on x.first_name = p.first_name
    and x.mid_name = p.mid_name
    and x.last_name = p.last_name
```

Or, if you have a unique column in the table, say `id`, you can use `exists`:

```
select p.*
from person p
where exists (
    select 1
    from person p1
    where 
        p1.id <> p.id
        and p1.first_name = p.first_name
        and p1.mid_name = p.mid_name
        and p1.last_name = p.last_name
)
```

Finally, if you are running MySQL 8.0, you can do a window count:

```
select * 
from (
    select 
        p.*,
        count(*) over(partition by first_name, mid_name, last_name) cnt
    from person p
) p
where cnt > 1
```

For performance with these queries, you want an index on `person(first_name, mid_name, last_name)` (add the `id` to that composite index if you are using the second solution).

Comment: The problem with ours is that we are using mysql5.0 and its not able to do those functions

Comment: @ShengZhang: did you test the queries? I would be surprised if the first two solutions did not work, even in this ancient version of MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an inner join to achieve this, the following query will return all rows that have duplicate First_Name, Mid_Name, Last_Name:

```
SELECT P1.* FROM Person P1
    INNER JOIN Person P2 ON P1.id != P2.id
WHERE (
    P1.First_Name = P2.First_Name 
        AND P1.Mid_Name = P2.Mid_Name 
        AND P1.Last_Name = P2.Last_Name
    )
```

If you have a large table(too many rows on it), I don't think this is a perfect solution!

#### Update:

```
SELECT P1.* FROM Person P1
    INNER JOIN Person P2 ON P1.id != P2.id
                    AND P1.First_Name = P2.First_Name
                    AND P1.Mid_Name = P2.Mid_Name
                    AND P1.Last_Name = P2.Last_Name
```

#### Example:

**Table:**
[image]

**Query results:**
[image]